# Prevent AI Shaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an AI which is a goalkeeper which tries to stop as many balls going in to the goal. There can be more than one ball heading towards the goal. The AI constantly checks (checks once a frame) which ball is the closest and tries to stop the closest ball.

Lets say the goalkeeper is in the middle of the goal and two balls, ball 1 and ball 2, one heading towards the right and the other towards the left of the goal. Both of which are the same distance away from the goal (or both distance are very close) . The goalkeeper starts to shake.

I am guessing this occurs because at one frame ball 1 is closest so it moves towards ball 1 and then the next frame ball 2 is the closest so it moves towards ball 2...then ball 1 then ball 2 then ball 1...etc.

How do I prevent this from happening? If someone wants to provide coding i am using Unity engine and coding in C#.

**EDIT 1:** Both balls are traveling at the same rate.

**EDIT 2:** The code I am using to check for the closest ball. This is done every frame.

```
GameObject FindClosestBall() {
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ball");
    GameObject closest;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a dumb goalkeeper. what if there's 2 balls moving towards the goal at rate X, and a 3rd ball very far away moving at rate "ludicrously fast". the goalkeeper would be getting in position for the two "close" balls, only to have that 3rd ball scream past him

Comment: @MarcB I think I know how to solve that problem but I have not implemented it. What my problem right now is the shaking problem when two balls at same distance away and are moving towards the goal at the same rate.

Comment: I like Marc B's comment.  Maybe look at velocity as a factor.

Comment: Simple. The goalkeeper is shaking because he constantly changes his mind. It happens to humans as well: would you like meal A or B? "uh....A......not wait, B......second thought, A". And the solution is simple isn't? Let him make up his mind and don't change!

Comment: This is a bit of a scheduling problem where you're trying to maximize the number of balls stopped. You'll have to consider your goalkeeper's speed and the trajectories of the balls. Going after the nearest ball is basically just a heuristic and does not guarantee stopping the maximum number of balls.

Comment: More on the heuristic: an intelligent way of doing this is to estimate the arrival time and position of the balls. Assuming the goalkeeper moves only left to right, the positions form a straight line. Now this is the classic computer science problem of figuring out a plan to move along this line to catch the maximum number of balls, considering the moving ability and position of the goalkeeper as well. But all that requires the goalkeeper to at least keep track of which ball is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try setting a threshold that must be met for two distances to be considered unequal.

For example, suppose you pick a threshold of 0.5:

Then if Ball 1 is at a distance of 4.8 and Ball 2 is at a distance of 5.0, you would consider them equal distance and choose between them by a tie-breaking method (ie, pick ball 1 over ball 2, because 1 < 2).

Adjust the threshold until it works well.

Comment: In addition to the threshold idea, once the goalie has decided to go after one of the balls, don't let him change his mind until the other ball "becomes closer".

Comment: This seems like a good idea but I am not sure how i will implement it exactly. I have added the code I use to find closest ball in my post. Where and how should I add this threshold?

Comment: @JohnDoe You can simply change the condition in your if statement from `curDistance < distance` to `Math.abs(curDistance - distance) < threshold` and define threshold as appropriate.

Comment: @Pualpro I changed my code to factor in velocity and time. I implemented a threshold on time and it seems to have no more shaking. Thank you.